# Export Amazon RDS serverless snapshot to Big Query

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds, snapshot, aws-aurora-serverless

I want to export my RDS serverless snapshot to big query. Sadly we cannot export serverless snapshot to s3. Any efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I haven't tried it personally, but there is blog post for moving data from MySQL RDS to Google BigQuery. This may help with your query.

https://medium.com/foxintelligence-inside/ingest-data-from-rds-mysql-to-google-bigquery-a8463885d8f3

Comment: Thanks I have already seen it. But it will be really helpful if we can directly export serverless RDS snapshot to S3 Bucket. see the limitations here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html#aurora-serverless.limitations

Answer (score 0):

- I restored a snapshot to a normal db instance(not serverless).
- Created a snapshot again from newly created db instance and copied it to a region tokyo. Then exported it to s3.
- From S3 we have options to load the data into big query
- Note: Only some regions support snapshot exports to s3 bucket.